# Unable to loop through a list of dict in python

Tags: python

I have a dict as follows:

```
{   u'has_more': False,
    u'is_limited': True,
    u'latest': u'1501149118.071555',
    u'messages': [   {   u'text': u'--Sharp 1.9 DM\n--Modifying and testing DM script for bypassing existing sonumber validation and add line items',
                         u'ts': u'1501149054.047400',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U0HN06ZB9'},
                     {   u'text': u'-- support to engineering on Licensing infra upgrade to 3.6\n   - created a new key for qa on current 3.5 ubuntu 12 instance\n   - added that key to the instance , created the ami and shared it with QA\n   - short discussion with Navin on same',
                         u'ts': u'1501148934.002719',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U02RRQJG1'},
                     {   u'inviter': u'U03FE3Z7D',
                         u'subtype': u'channel_join',
                         u'text': u'<@U0HN06ZB9|shikhar.rastogi> has joined the channel',
                         u'ts': u'1501148921.998107',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U0HN06ZB9'},
                     {   u'inviter': u'U03FE3Z7D',
                         u'subtype': u'channel_join',
                         u'text': u'<@U02RRQJG1|himani> has joined the channel',
                         u'ts': u'1501148328.777625',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U02RRQJG1'},
                     {   u'text': u'something like ^^^^',
                         u'ts': u'1501148318.773838',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
                     {   u'text': u'-- This is test \n-- Not\n-- test1\n-- Test b',
                         u'ts': u'1501148309.770614',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
                     {   u'text': u'<!channel>  can all of you start putting some random crap in same format as shift handoff',
                         u'ts': u'1501148287.762336',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
                     {   u'text': u'<!channel>  can all of you start putting some random crap in same format as shift handoff',
                         u'ts': u'1501148287.762161',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
                     {   u'text': u'sjvnsv',
                         u'ts': u'1501138569.469475',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
                     {   u'text': u'-- Test1 \n-- Leave this ASAP',
                         u'ts': u'1501136157.933720',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'user': u'U03FE3Z7D'},
                     {   u'bot_id': u'B19LZG1A5',
                         u'subtype': u'bot_message',
                         u'text': u'This is crazy',
                         u'ts': u'1501075281.418010',
                         u'type': u'message',
                         u'username': u'TEST_BOT'}],
    u'ok': True,
    u'oldest': u'1500820472.964970'}
```

Now i am trying to extract 2 things 1st is the `user` and its corresponding `text`, but somehow i am not able to get this using following :

```
json_objects = json.loads(r.text)
for i in json_objects:
    print json_objects['messages'][i]['user']
    print json_objects['messages'][i]['text']
```

The above throws a error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    get_channel_messages()
  File "clean_test.py", line 38, in get_channel_messages
    print json_objects['messages'][i]['user']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

The above should actually get the `user` and calls a user_detail() meathod to get the name and come back, once this is done, i want the content to be dumped into a file in the following manner

```
username1:
    -- text
username2:
    -- text2
```

Comment: I think you are iterating over the wrong iterable. try `for i in json_objects['messages']:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to iterate over the indices of the list, not iterate over the keys of the outer dict

```
json_objects = json.loads(r.text)
for i in range(len(json_objects['messages'])):
    print json_objects['messages'][i]['user']
    print json_objects['messages'][i]['text']
```

Or another way would be (the Pythonic Way):

```
for i in json_objects['messages']:
   print i['user']
   print i['text']
```

Comment: the second approach here, iterating over the items in a collection themselves (instead of iterating over their indices), is the pythonic solution.

Comment: Yes, I did that because OP seemed to be doing the other way so I corrected that. I should add that in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating with dictionary and trying to access list. Try with this

```
for i in json_objects['messages']:
    print i['user']
    print i['text']
```

Comment: @Kittystone, yup agreed, i mistakenly written 'json_objects['messages']' in print statements.. )